# Browser validation message min/max

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, validation, woocommerce

Is there a way to change browsers validation message

Please check attached image.

I am currently using wooCommerce[image]

Currently it show less then or equal to X numbers I want to change to Request a qoute for more than X number of items.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `oninvalid` attribute with `this.setCustomValidity` function. `this.setCustomValidity` function will display the custom message on invalidated of the field.

So you can simply add this into your `<input>` tag.

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cannot enter value greater that 15')"
```

Check this code snippet

```html
<form action="/action_page_post.php" method="post">
  <input type="number" step='1' min='1' max='15' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cannot enter value greater that 15')">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Just input numbers more that 15 and click the submit button and observe the message. You can further tweak it in your own way.

Comment: min and max refers to values not digits so you might want to edit your answer.

Comment: Can you please check now. I have updated my answer and it is still not fine tell me i will try to improve more. But if it does please mark it and up vote it